# Verification using express-mysql-session

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, express-session

As I'm new to node programming, I have started to make a dummy web site and I want to implement session management using the existing library express-mysql-session.

I went through the  [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session) of this package. I have followed the given steps for creating the session variables/ data entry into the tables. I am even able to get the data entered into the table. Though I am very confused about what should I do for the actual verification. I'm storing the user's email and id that I have imported from other 'users' table for login authentication, which is being stored in the data column of the session table.
[session table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7Pju.png).

As in the documentation, it only shows how to store a session variable into the DB, not the verification step. What I'm thoroughly confused by is what parameter is to be exactly used for authentication/session. Is it the session_id column value that is to be used for it and if so, do I store this value in the global variable and access it each time from the table?

I have been unable to find any examples for the same using this very package, so I don't have any context for the next step. If someone even has an example explaining this package, please can you share its source with me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using this library?

Comment: @CharlieH I want to implement session management using this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library is based on [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session), which can be used to manage sessions. The express-session library saves data in the server side(memory) and express-mysql-session provides a way to save the session data to a MySql table.

You should first experiment with the express-session library and then connect it to mysql using the library at question.

It is pretty straightforward to use the express-session library.

> To store or access session data, simply use the request property
>   req.session, which is (generally) serialized as JSON by the store, so
>   nested objects are typically fine. For example below is a
>   user-specific view counter:

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I really wanted was to know how the mysql library will interact with the session. Will the session parameters be extracted automatically by my server file or will I have to somehow use it by myself?

Comment: You have to use express-session as mentioned in the answer. See how the snippet  maintain a counter by tracking the sessions.